# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]

Tags: php, bots, telegram

how to fix this issue

```
[09-Nov-2022 23:37:10 Asia/Tehran] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'Ecko_acpbot.message_log' doesn't exist in ******/inc/database.class.php:36
Stack trace:
#0 ******/inc/database.class.php(36): PDOStatement->execute()
#1 ******/inc/message.class.php(56): Database->execute()
#2 ******/index.php(8): Message->GetLast5Messages()
#3 {main}
  thrown in ******/inc/database.class.php on line 36
```

i try to use this CPTelegram from [github](https://github.com/alikhansari/CPTelegram)

so how to fix this one

Comment: The error message seems clear, you're trying to use a table that you haven't created in your database.

Comment: That software expects there to be a `message_log` table. But there's no documentation explaining what the columns are supposed to be, so I don't know how you're supposed to fix it.

Comment: I suggest you contact the author of the library. But it looks like it's been abandoned, nothing in that repo has been updated in 6 years.